# The most referring to the majority of people

Tags: word-usage, idioms

> Let's do what benefits the most.

Is this correct usage of `the most` when the meaning is the following?

> Let's do what benefits the majority of the people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound right to me, you would have to use a noun after it
So:

Let's do what benefits the most people

Comment: Yes, “the majority” can be readily interpreted as “the majority of people” in the right context - you hear “majority” and you think people (even though it can refer to things sometimes too). But, in contrast “the most” often refers to things rather than people and so “the most people” can’t be shortened to “the most”.